# dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8, odoo-8

i look this error i all internet but i really dont understand the answers, i hard to understand what is the function given to you or what it has to give to you, i let you my code i hope any one help

What im looking for?
i need to put into act_user_suc the users sucursal_u fro res_users thats all and i relly apreciated the help

```
class bodega(osv.Model):
    _name = 'bodega'
    _description = 'datos generales'

    def dame_usuario(self, cr, uid, ids, fieldname, arg, context=None):
        digits = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context).company_id.currency_id
        return digits

    _columns = {            
                'name': fields.char("Name", required=True),
                'act_user_suc': fields.function(dame_usuario, type='many2one', readonly = True),
                }
    _defaults = {
                }
bodega()
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?  What is it actually doing?  What exception or error are you getting?

Comment: first i have an error in the code in this line digits = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context).company_id.currency_id because i have like this digits = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context).sucursal_u, look im going to explain better what i want, i have a class res.users and i inherit a field sucursal_u, i need to store in other class' field called act_user_suc the same data than sucursal_u i hope and wish you understand thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update few things in code.

Specify `relation` attribute in `fields.function`, you have defined that `many2one` as field type but it's related to which model ?.

And other things is that `company_id.currency_id` it gives you an browsable object not an id.

So try following,

```py
def dame_usuario(self, cr, uid, ids, fieldname, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    for obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        result[obj.id] = False
        user = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context)
        if user and user.sucursal_u:
            result[obj.id] = user.sucursal_u.id
    return res

    _columns = {            
                'name': fields.char("Name", required=True),
                'act_user_suc': fields.function(dame_usuario,
                    type='many2one', readonly = True, relation='sucursales'),
                }
```

Comment: first i have an error in the code in this line digits = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context).company_id.currency_id because i have like this digits = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context).sucursal_u i have tried what you told me but still the same error, look im going to explain better what i want, i have a class res.users and i inherit a field sucursal_u, i need to store in other class' field called act_user_suc the same data than sucursal_u i hope and wish you understand thanks for your time and help

Comment: Can you paste that code also ? In which you have added sucursal_u field.

Comment: class res_users(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.users'  
    
    _columns = {            
                'por_sucursal': fields.boolean('Por Sucursal', help="Es por Sucursal"), 
                'sucursal_u' : fields.many2one('sucursales', 'Sucursal', help="Selecciona la sucursal"),           
                'tecnichian': fields.boolean('Tecnico', help="Es de servicio"),
                'sup_monitoreo': fields.boolean('Supervisar monitoreo', help="Es supervisora de monitoreo"),
                              }

Comment: itried to do it with a related field but the related field its empty doesnt get the value from res_users.sucursal_u, i tried with inhertis and related field and also didnt work

Comment: Like Dr Frankestein said: "it's aliveeeee" it worked "empiro" i owe you  my live thanks for all i only changed result for res.